# Cluster algorithm which minimizes a distance while fulfilling a constraint

Tags: clustering, optimization

I have data of 90 persons.

Data of a person:
- x coordinate
- y coordinate
- score (1 to 6)

I want to form groups of 9 people each so that:
- the distance between people in one group is as small as possible
- people with the same coordinates are in different groups
- people within a group should have different scores

I am not expecting a full-fledged algorithm but rather hints in the right direction. So far I am using a simple k-means algorithm which forms groups so that the distance between people gets minimized however the two other constraints are not considered, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

I found [this article](https://cs.gmu.edu/~carlotta/teaching/CS775-s10/readings/ConsTutorialFinal.pdf) on "Clustering with Constraints" to be a helpful resource to what you're talking about:

Credit:
Clustering with Constraints
Incorporating Prior Knowledge
into Clustering
Adapted from a Tutorial of Sugato Basu and Ian Davidson (SDM 2005)

Answer (score 0):

You are describing a variation on [optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_optimization), maximize a real function by systematically choosing input values from within an allowed set and computing the value of the function. Specifically, a variation called [linear programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming) where you to maximize the similarity (similarity is the inverse of distance) subject to a couple of constraints:

[image]

Comment: I thought about defining a cost function and then minimize it. But I couldn't figure out how to properly do updates. I can't compute a gradient and use gradient descent. Do you have recommendations on how to do updates?

Comment: Gradient descent is not the best optimization technique for clustering. Expectation–maximization (EM) is superior for clustering.